# iOS Push Notification System Server

Tags: ios, azure, notifications, push-notification

I am searching for a solution to create a Push Notification system for a Unity iOS game.
In this good [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1), I see that I need a server.
The aim is to provide general notifications such as App Update, New content, etc...

I have some questions in mind:

- What solution can I use to create a notification server ? It seems that Windows Azure can handle that, no ?
- How can I administrate the notifications ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Azure can easily handle your push notification needs with **APNS** (iOS push) support in both **Mobile Services** and **Notification Hubs**.
**Mobile Services** require you to do the administration / management yourself while **Notification Hubs** will handle all of that (Show you logs, diagnostics on successful pushes, errors, bad registrations) as well as other features like tag based registration (enables pushing to a specific user, among other things) and templates.
If you're just looking at doing **Notifications** and don't also need to store data, I would take a look at **Notification Hubs** (http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/services/notification-hubs/).
As far as Unity support, there is nothing provided by Microsoft today.
However, **BitRave** has an open source plugin for Azure Mobile Services and Unity (http://www.bitrave.com/azure-mobile-services-for-unity-3d/).
**Notification Hubs** has everything (registering for push, triggering pushes, etc) exposed via a REST API though so if you're comfortable making HTTP requests with Unity, it should be pretty trivial to connect to **Notification Hubs** (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn223264.aspx).

As for triggering push notifications, you have a lot of options with Azure including: triggering from your iOS app, using Mobile Services, using a website / cloud service / VM.  It depends on what sort of server / triggering architecture you might need.

Comment: Unity has a system for handling push notification [NotificationServices](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/NotificationServices.html). But there is no tutorial and is it compatible with azure Notification Hubs.

Comment: It sounds like that it just the client side (i.e. your Unity app).  You'd still need to send the token you get from that to your Notification Hub by making a web request.  It looks like you would do that from the RegisterForRemoteNotificationTypes method's Update function: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/NotificationServices.RegisterForRemoteNotificationTypes.html

Comment: I made some researches and I know a little more about the notification process. I need to register the device on the server. But all tutorial I found are event based push notifications. Is it possible to send notification to inform about an update for example. I think this needs a sort of cron job.

Comment: You do need some sort of event to trigger a push.  Whether that's one device running the app telling your server to push something out or a cron type job would depend on your app's architecture.  Azure Mobile Services features a handy Scheduler feature for running  scripts either on a predefined schedule or on demand.  You could use this feature to easily trigger a push notification to your app whenever you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't make it work. I followed the tutorial except the sending notification part.
I don't know how to add the Windows Azure SDK in the XCode project generated by Unity because I don't have any AppDelegate.h or AppDelegate.m.
And when I call RegisterForRemoteNotificationTypes I don't receive any token... I am quite lost, I don't know where the issue comes from.

Comment: Good news, I am receiving the token ! But in the http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/NotificationServices.RegisterForRemoteNotificationTypes.html they use an url but what url should I use to contact my Hub ?

Comment: Take a look at this article for information on how you can send your Token to your Notification Hub: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn495631.aspx.  The example is in javascript but you'll use the same format for creating your URL: 

var registrationPath = hub.hubPath + "/Registrations";
    var serverUrl = hub.endpoint + registrationPath
        + "?api-version=2013-04";

Answer (score 0):

Checkout Parse.com. Dev license is free and you get 1 million API calls and a ton of Push Notification pushes. My experience with Azure is that it's pretty lackluster and difficult to do some of the things that Parse.com can do.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I don't need high level push functionalities. The aim is to send simple push notifications like: "Hey, there's a game update !" or "Hey, check out the new levels !". We already have an Azure account that's why I was asking for Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Use pushsharp . This works for all the devices and it's free

Comment: Pushsharp is just a server side library.  One would still need to deploy this somewhere (i.e. Azure, a .net server, etc)